# Performance com imagens externas

Tags: html

Olá!

No meu site tem uma área de posts e cada post contem sua imagem. A imagem original é do tamanho de 660px x 400px, salvo esse tamanho em um host de imagem para poder pegar na metag `URL` para apresentar nas redes sociais com uma qualidade boa, até ai funciona legal.

Mas no site eu crio uma outra imagem de tamanho 330x168 para servir como *thumb* do post e jogo na s3 e faço sua chamada. Porém, na s3 me retorna de uma forma que não fica legal para o Google Analytics.

Então minha dúvida é se posso pegar essa imagem de 660x400 que está em um outro host e carregar na tag `img` com a url mas colocando com o tamanho 330x186.

Isso pode ser lento ou ha uma outra solução viável? Eu acho que com isso não seria necessário enviar para s3 uma img com tamanho menor. Pegaria apenas a original e diminuiria seu tamanho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Posso pegar essa imagem de 660x400 que está em um outro host e carregar na tag img com a url mas colocando com o tamanho 330x186?

Sim! A tag `img` tem os atributos `height` e `width` exatamente para isso!

```
<img src="link da imagem" alt="texto para leitores de página" width="186" height="330">
```

Os valores de `height` e `width` já são em pixels, então não existe necessidade de especificar a medida.

Se são várias imagens que queira fazer isso, basta adicionar uma classe a elas e por CSS especificar esses valores.

```
<img class="img_reduzida" src="link da imagem" alt="texto para leitores de página">

.img_reduzida {
  height: 330px;
  width: 186px;
}
```

E, se dentro dessa classe, quiser dar algum tratamento especial a uma imagem específica, basta dar a ela um ID único.

```
<img class="img_reduzida" id="img1" src="link da imagem" alt="texto para leitores de pagina">

.img_reduzida #img1 {
  height: 440px;
  width: 660px;
}
```

Comment: A minha maior dúvida é se pode ficar lento o carregamento da página.

Comment: Nesse caso, vai depender do browser do usuário, e não do servidor em si.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.